# jquery error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on website which works fine when accessed via the web. However, when I forked the project and opened the html file saved on my computer, the javascript doesn't load, and the console gives the above error.

Now, the bizarre part is that this only happens sometimes. If refresh immediately, I usually get the error again. However, if I wait 10-20 minutes, change nothing, then refresh the browser, the error goes away. I'll keep working on the project for half an hour, and then the error will come back. I can't find any sort of pattern between my actions and the prevalence of this error.

I honestly have no clue what's going on, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That error is because of your server.  Look at the network tab to see where you're redirecting.

Comment: Could you help me interpret the network tab? I'm very new to web development. To me, it looks like the page is loading https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js about 20 times, and failing on the last one. I don't know what to make of this or how to fix it.

Comment: Look at the response headers from one of the redirects.

Comment: Also, use Google's CDN instead.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! It seems clearing my browser cookies solves the problem. How would I go about using Google's CDN?

Comment: Google it.  https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/